# multiple workflow tasks get stuck in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I’m fairly new in programming and I need a hand for a problem I cannot solve.
I have created a sequential approval workflow using SharePoint 2007 and Visual Studio 2010. And the tutorial in this page: http://www.sheltonblog.com/archive/2007/11/21/how-to-video-building-a-basic-approval-workflow-with-sharepoint.aspx

Everything seems fine I can create the approval forma and approve it!
However if I need to have to approval workflows at the same time, it simply get stuck!
I’ve tried to Troubleshoot with the Visual Studio Debug and check in the workflow logs but nothing seems to be picked up.
Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been in the same situation following that tutorial I found that the problem was the fact that he uses the same guid for the task, therefore if you have multiple tasks with the same Guid Sharepoint gets "confused" and does nothing.
To solve the issue have to:

Go in the designer.
Select the create task.
Remove the Guid
Click on the ...
Select Bind to a `New Member` and `Create new Field` the click OK

in the code behind  in the CreateTask Method use the following code to have the TaskID Guid created anew everytime:

```
createTaskt1_TaskId1 = Guid.NewGuid();
```

PS Change the  createTaskt1_TaskId1 with the name of your property.